# Gradle shadowJar deletes required SQL driver

Tags: gradle, hive, fatjar

I'm using the `shadowJar` Gradle target provided by the [com.github.johnrengelman.shadow](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/getting-started/#default-java-groovy-tasks) Gradle plugin to build up an application, which requires an `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` to connect to Kudu using Impala.

The problem is that when I use standard approach to import the driver in Scala:

```scala
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
```

- the shadow plugin removes it from the resulting JAR, implying an runtime error of:

  - `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`.

My `build.gradle` contains:

```
dependencies {
  implementation {
    "org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:1.2.1"
  }
}
```

---

How do I instruct the shadow plugin not to delete the required dependency injected via a String?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution is to include the static type not via `Class.forName`, but using code by importing it:

```scala
import java.sql.DriverManager
import org.apache.hive.jdbc.{HiveConnection, HiveDriver}

class Foo {

  // Register Hive Driver this way to prevent shadowing to cut it off
  new HiveDriver()

  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password) match {
    case connection: HiveConnection =>
       ...
  }
}
```

This way, the shadow plugin is officially informed about the fact that the Driver is actually required.